# Support viewing old editions of the question on iPad app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

I want to see the old revisions of this question. Is there a way to show this in the iPad app? If not, please add this to your wish list.

[image]

Comment: Hello? Is there any mod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now see revisions on the beta version of the app. This feature will be available in the Appstore app in the next update.

1. Tap on the **"Edited by ..."** text on the bottom of a question or answer

   > [image]
2. The revisions UI!

   > [image]

Comment: Thanks. Why does it take so long to  this feature?

Comment: @Ooker Well, I think implementing the diff engine on mobile was a bit tough, and there are always bugs and features competing for our limited resources :)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do it directly from the app.

What i do when i want to see the history is to open in Chrome (that option seems to be enabled for me, but you can use Safari), and check the revisions from there.